# rsync a directory tree with optional overlay tree

Tags: rsync

I maintain a directory structure containing dirs and files that I regularly push to ~50 hosts, which are divided into 3 groups that have slightly different needs - minor mods in a couple of files.

So ideally I would have 4 directories:

```
/path/to/sync/common/   <- common files
/path/to/sync/group1/   <- group1 specific only
/path/to/sync/group2/   <- group2 specific only
/path/to/sync/group3/   <- group3 specific only
```

Then I'd run an rsync like

```
rsync -av --overlay /path/to/sync/groupN /path/to/sync/common remotehost:
```

Thinking in terms of a list of files to be transferred, I would like:

- anything present in common/ added to the file list; then
- anything present in groupN/ added to the list, clobbering anything already there

I realise I could populate the list myself and use `--files-from=<LIST>` but I would rather have rsync work it out *if* possible.  I can't think of a simple way to populate the list myself that isn't clunky (second prize for pointing one out!)

Comment: Calling it an overlay is a actually pretty relevant keyword: `overlayfs` has been in the Linux kernel since v3.18. You could mount an overlayfs that provides a merged view on multiple directories like this: `mount overlay /mnt/foo -t overlay -o lower=/path/to/group1:/path/to/common` (double-check the syntax and read the relevant part of the kernel docs directory; I'm typing this from memory)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this that will work, by merging the trees locally first.

```
TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
cp -r /path/to/sync/common/* $TEMPDIR
cp -r -f /path/to/sync/groupN/* $TEMPDIR
rsync -av $TEMPDIR/* remotehost:
rm -r $TEMPDIR
```

I'd still prefer to do it with rsync though, to say on local cp'ing.